# Dash server not running even after changing ports

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am learning python Dash hence used the same code given in the Dash website here - https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started but when I am running in idle it is giving me an error as below I used the normal server as given in the website then changed the port still nothing works

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=5500)
```

here is the error

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5500/
Debugger PIN: 419-348-850
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shaum\Documents\Python_Dash\testa.py", line 32, in <module>
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=5500)
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 2026, in run_server
    self.server.run(port=port, debug=debug, **flask_run_options)
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 985, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 670, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 218, in echo
    file = _default_text_stdout()
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 675, in func
    rv = wrapper_func()
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 436, in get_text_stdout
    rv = _get_windows_console_stream(sys.stdout, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\shaum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 295, in _get_windows_console_stream
    func = _stream_factories.get(f.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my system, no error thrown. What do you mean by "running in idle"?

Comment: I'm guessing that refers to [Python IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE)

Comment: Change the last line run_server(debug=False) and see if you get the app to work. Sometimes debug mode being True doesn't go well with certain IDEs or environments.

Comment: Try to run your script from command prompt, it should help.

Comment: I sometimes have random problems with running my Dash server. A solution that worked for me in the past was restarting my system. Nowadays however I just start to run my server via gunicorn when the problem occurs which still works fine.